# Issues using excel addin with python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to use python and win32com to load an excel workbook into an instance of excel that I had opened that has an addin active

The code I'm using to open the file is this.

```
excel=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
source = excel.Workbooks.Open('test.xlsm')
```

The problem is that this is actually opening a separate instance of excel without the addin active.

I have tried opening that addin file and then the workbook like this.

```
excel=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
addin = excel.Workbooks.Open('addin.xla')
source = excel.Workbooks.Open('test.xlsm')
```

but when I try and use the addin I get an error similar to this.

> Can't run macro "sbex.xla!runQuery"

Any ideas would be helpful.